# Invalid read of size 8 in valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind shows following error message

```
==8584== Invalid read of size 8
==8584==  at0x4CA885D:VPR::VidSegment::getMCmean(std::vector<std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> >, std::allocator<std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> > > > const&) const (VidSegment.cpp:678)

==8584==    by 0x4CAE071: VPR::VidSegment::getSegments(std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> >, _IplImage const*) (VidSegment.cpp:234)


  vector<CvRect> VidSegment::getMCmean(const vector< vector<CvRect> >& majorCluster) const
  {
    vector<CvRect> meanvaluesN;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) majorCluster.size(); i++ )
    {
      int sumH=0, sumY=0, sumW=0, sumB=0;
      vector<CvRect> tempV = majorCluster[i];
      //Here-------------->
      for (int j = 0; j < (int) tempV.size(); j++)
      {
        sumH +=  tempV[j].height;
        sumW +=  tempV[j].width;
        sumY +=  tempV[j].y;
        sumB += (tempV[j].y + tempV[j].height);
      }
      sumH /= tempV.size();
      sumY /= tempV.size();
      sumW /= tempV.size();
      sumB /= tempV.size();
      meanvaluesN.push_back(cvRect(sumH, sumY, sumW, sumB));
    }
    return meanvaluesN;
  }
```

I couldn't find why it is showing above message.

Can anybody tell the reason for this?

I am getting following error message also

```
==8584== Address 0x960107c is 252 bytes inside a block of size 256 alloc'd 
==8584== at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298) 

==8584== by 0x4CA87A4: VPR::VidSegment::getMCmean(std::vector<std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> >, std::allocator<std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> > > > const&) const (new_allocator.h:89)
```

Comment: Which lines are 678 and 234?

Comment: 678 , in code i have  written //Here-------------->

Comment: Spare the obvious question, something against iterators? Just curious.

Comment: Please clarify where invalid read happens - usually it resides  before- or after- allocated block, in recently freed memory.

Comment: it shows at VidSegment.cpp +678, which corresponds to the line //Here--------------> in the above code

Comment: I am getting this also from above fun ==8584==  Address 0x960107c is 252 bytes inside a block of size 256 alloc'd
==8584==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==8584==    by 0x4CA87A4: VPR::VidSegment::getMCmean(std::vector<std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> >, std::allocator<std::vector<CvRect, std::allocator<CvRect> > > > const&) const (new_allocator.h:89)

Comment: How big do those vectors get?

Comment: majorCluster size usually10,  majorCluster[i] usually 15

Comment: Is it possible that any of the `tempV` vectors has size 0?  If so your code has undefined behavior (though I can't explain why it would result in what Valgrind is complaining about).  I'd also look for heap corruption before execution reaches this point - but there would be a similar mystery about why Valgrind wouldn't have complained about that.

Comment: tempV size is not Zero

Comment: I am running my application like this =>  valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./myApp . What all options I need to add to get "heap corruption"  using valgrind.

Comment: It's possible you're running into a false positive when the `tempV` vector is being initialized by copying `majorCluster[i]`.  Try changing the declaration for `tempV` to be a reference: `vector<CvRect> const& tempV(majorCluster[i]);`

Comment: I tried this also => const vector<CvRect> & tempV = majorCluster[i];

Comment: Also I am pushing vectors into majorCluster, only if size() is greater than 2, Also I changed into vector iterator

Comment: What is `class CvRect`?  From what you've posted I assumed it was a POD type, but the message about `operator new()` makes me wonder if it's managing a resource (and maybe doesn't properly follow the rule-of-3 or whatever the current equivalent is).  I think we've reached the point where we need to you to post a complete,  compilable example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: struct CvRect
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int width;
  int height;
}  It is from OpenCV